# PostgreSQL - Import from csv using function - csv file has column name with spaces

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.4

I have copied function(from one of the webportal and modified accordingly) to copy data from csv file to table. My Csv file is generated dynamically from reporting tool and column name has spaces in it (ex: "Date Desc", "item No")

Is it possible to replace spaces with _ using below function:

```
create or replace function public.load_csv_file
(
target_table text,
csv_path text,
col_count integer
)

returns void as $$

declare

iter integer; -- dummy integer to iterate columns with
col text; -- variable to keep the column name at each iteration
col_first text; -- first column name, e.g., top left corner on a csv file or     spreadsheet

begin
set schema 'public';

create table insert_from_csv ();

-- add just enough number of columns
for iter in 1..col_count
loop
    execute format('alter table insert_from_csv add column col_%s text;', iter);
end loop;

-- copy the data from csv file
execute format('copy insert_from_csv from %L with delimiter '','' quote ''"'' csv ', csv_path);

iter := 1;
col_first := (select col_1 from insert_from_csv limit 1);

-- update the column names based on the first row which has the column names
for col in execute format('select unnest(string_to_array(trim(temp_table::text, ''()''), '','')) from temp_table where col_1 = %L', col_first)
loop
    execute format('alter table insert_from_csv rename column col_%s to %s', iter, col);
    iter := iter + 1;
end loop;

-- delete the columns row
execute format('delete from insert_from_csv where %s = %L', col_first, col_first);

-- change the temp table name to the name given as parameter, if not blank
if length(target_table) > 0 then
    execute format('alter table insert_from_csv rename to %I', target_table);
end if;

end;

$$ language plpgsql;
```

And 
Received Error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DESC"
> LINE 1: delete from insert_from_csv where Date DESC = 'Date DESC'
>                                                 ^
> QUERY:  delete from insert_from_csv where Date DESC = 'Date DESC'
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function load_csv_file(text,text,integer) line 34 at EXECUTE
> ```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: your error message does not reconcile with code you provided, please update the post with code samples with `delete from insert_from_csv where ` code

Comment: Then i am using this function to create a table and load data from CSV

    
select load_csv_file('items_per_month','C:\Testing\1_576.csv' ,2)

Comment: `execute format('delete from insert_from_csv where %I = %L', col_first, col_first);`

Comment: Thanks wildplasser, it worked.